# Does unzipping a file on a remote server download the files back to my local?

Tags: windows, compression, zip

I need to copy a high number of files to a remote windows server. I am connecting to it via VPN and then browsing to the remote folder in Windows Explorer.  Problem is uploading is really slow, especially if I don't zip up the files first.  I do have the option to upload a zip file and then unzip them on the remote server.

My question is, if I unzip the file on the remote server (via Windows explorer), does the built-in windows unzip tool first download the zip file to some temp area on my local first?  That would defeat the purpose of zipping it in the first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are accessing the remote server shares via standard windows sharing (doesn't matter if it is over LAN or VPN). Windows treats it as another local disk.

Everything you do with files stored there is done by the CPU on your PC. So the unzipping will be done on your CPU. If you have enough RAM, it won't download the zip file from remote server again as it still will be in cache, but it has to write the unzipped copy there anyway. It doesn't download a copy of the file, it just issues read requests towards the "disk" and waits until the data arrives.

And yes, using windows shares via VPN is very slow due to the large number of small packets Windows need to send/receive for every action. It doesn't matter on local LAN with ping (round-trip) times of 0.1ms, but even with RTT of 10ms, it is painfully slow as each read request is a separate network packet.

The only solution for you would be to run the unzipping process itself on the remote server. For example use Remote Desktop (RDP) to connect to the remote server and unzip the file there. As the unzipping will be done by the CPU of the remote server, it will read/write the files on its local drive.